# Check checkboxes in Angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, checkbox

I'm new to angular so please excuse me if I'm going to say / ask something very stupid.
I followed this example to add checkboxes to my form:
[enter link description here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular)

Everything works good, I can save the ids of my checkboxes into the database.
The problem is that when I try to modify the form I can't check the checkboxes that were checked before and saved into my database ( a list of strings, I know it's not ok but for now I'll keep it like this).
I receive the list, I transform it into an array to iterate and then I tried to set value to true to the controls but nothing is working. 
Can someone help me?
These is my file:
addmodify.component.ts :`

```
          public natura = [
                   { id: 1, name: 'si'},
                   { id: 2, name: 'af'},
                   { id: 3, name: 'erg'},
                   { id: 4, name: 'rid'},
                   { id: 5, name: 'ridc'},
                   { id: 6, name: 'qual'},
                   { id: 7, name: 'Ridte'},
                   { id: 8, name: 'Alt'}
                ];
             constructor(
                    private _fb: FormBuilder,
                    private _avRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                    private _suggerimentoService: SuggerimentoService,
                    private _nuovoPartecipanteService: NuovoPartecipanteService,
                    private toasterService: ToasterService,
                    private translate: TranslateService,
                    private _router: Router) {          
                      const controls = this.natura.map(c => new FormControl(false));        
                        this.suggerimentoForm = this._fb.group({                    
                            natura: new FormArray(controls, minSelectedCheckboxes(1))
                    }); 
controls[0].setValue(true);   // this works, on init it checks the first checkbox.           
                }
    ngOnInit() {
      if (this.id > 0) {              
         this._suggerimentoService.getSuggerimentoById(this.id)
            .subscribe(resp => {    
                const controls = this.natura.map(c => new FormControl(false));
                const listNatura = resp.natura.split(','); // here resp.natura is ="4,5" and then listNatura will be an array with those 2 values

        // this is how I tried to set the checkboxes checked but it's wrong
                listNatura.forEach(function (value) {
                console.log('valore=',value);
                controls[0].setValue(true);
          });        
                resp.natura = this.natura;   // I have to do this because if not (if I leave resp.natura a string) I'm getting  an error.
                this.suggerimentoForm.setValue(resp);
         }, error => this.errorMessage = error);
       }  
     }
```

and this is my html file:

```
<form class="k-form" [formGroup]="suggerimentoForm" (ngSubmit)="save()" #formDir="ngForm" novalidate>
   <div formArrayName="natura" *ngFor="let nat of suggerimentoForm.controls.natura.controls; let i = index">
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" class="k-checkbox " value="{{natura[i].id}}" id="{{natura[i].id}}">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label"  for="{{natura[i].id}}">{{natura[i].name}}</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: could you please share your html code ?

Comment: I've just edited my question

Comment: Can you post a [_minimal_ example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue you're experiencing, with a reproduction? The code is very hard to read because there's so much unnecessary clutter.

Comment: I edited once again my code, where is the unnecessary clutter?( I'll delete it) I cannot post a minimal example I'm very sorry. The problem is that I cannot check the checkboxes.

Comment: add in input tag : [checked]="bolleanValue", where bolleanValue is true or false based on your data from database

Comment: I agree with Lazar. There is a lot going on that could be cleaned up.
You're creating formControls in the constructor and in the NgInit(). I really can't follow your logic here.
Can you refactor your logic into small functions.
private CreateFormGroup();
private SetCheckBoxes(data: any[])
private GetCheckBoxData()

Comment: As I said I'm new to angular so I know that my code is non clean. I'm creating formControls in the constructor  and then in the NgInit() because I save and modify the form using one component. I'll try to refactor my code. Thank you.